# Apache, как запретить отдельным virtualhost-ам создавать исходящие соединения (доступ в Интернет)?

Tags: apache, cgi, virtual-hosts

Имеется сервер Apache, необходимо в целях безопасности запретить отдельным virtualhost-ам создавать исходящие соединения (доступ в Интернет).
Т.е. из вне запросы обрабатываться должны, а все создаваемые скриптами (php,cgi, etc...) исходящие соединения должны блокироваться.

Как это сделать стандартными средствами Apache?
Если стандартными невозможно, то существует ли возможность путём написания своего плагина?

Comment: Похоже проблема решается использованием mpm_itk_module + iptables. https://serverfault.com/questions/425739/use-assignuserid-as-variable-in-apache-mpm-itk  https://habr.com/post/82933/ Путём создания пользователей для заданных хостов и настройки правил iptables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На хосте с Apache, установить модуль mpm_itk_module.

`# yum install httpd-itk`

По необходимости, создать пользователей и группы для хостов

В конфигурации виртуальных хостов добавить следующие строки, привязывающие их к нужным пользователям и группам:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId user group
</IfModule>
```

Модуль можно и не устанавливать, если политика блокировки будет одинаковой для всех виртуальных хостов.

В конфигурации iptables, любым способом (скрипт или посредством iptables-services) добавить следующие правила:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner group -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

в место, или вместе с критерием --gid-owner, по Вашему выбору можно использовать опцию --uid-owner, либо другие критерии, см. документацию.

Итого: входящие уже установленные соединения - будут обрабатываться нормально, а соединения созданные по инициативе скриптов виртуального хоста - будут блокироваться.